# Converting unsigned chars to signed integer

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

I have an unsigned char array with 2 elements that represents a signed integer. How can I convert these 2 bytes into a signed integer?

**Edit**: The unsigned char array is in little endian

Comment: You gotta watch out for endiannes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: There are several ways in which two `unsigned char` could represent a signed integer. You should be more specific on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For maximum safety, use

```
int i = *(signed char *)(&c[0]);
i *= 1 << CHAR_BIT;
i |= c[1];
```

for big endian. Swap `c[0]` and `c[1]` for little endian.

(Explanation: we interpret the byte at `c[0]` as a `signed char`, then arithmetically left shift it in a portable way, then add in `c[1]`.)

Comment: As I told after, if you just cast the unsigned char to signed char you risk the sign bit to be expanded. Better mask the result with 0x0000FFFF to be sure the sign bit is low.

Comment: @Mr.Gate, I'm not "just" casting `unsigned char` to `signed char`. I'm using a pointer cast to reinterpret the bit pattern as `signed char`, then promoting to `int`.

Comment: Most compilers **do not ignore** aliasing rules. GCC will almost surely generate code that fails to do what you want unless you pass it special options.

Comment: the `(int16_t *)c` may induce SIGBUS on many RISC processor, and reduce performance on IA86 architecture.

Comment: @R..: You're right. I thought I had to turn it on explicitly in GCC, but it's implied in `-O2`. Removed the pointer trick.

Answer (score 5):

wrap them up in a union:

```
union {
  unsigned char a[2];
  int16_t smt;
} number;
```

Now after filling the array you can use this as `number.smt`

Comment: @VGE: `short` to `int` conversion is well-defined. Though I'd recommend using `int16_t` instead of `short`.

Answer (score 1):

It depend of endianness.
Something for big endian :

```
unsigned char x[2];
short y = (x[0] << 8) | x[1]
```

Something for little endian :

```
unsigned char x[2];
short y = (x[1] << 8) | x[0]
```

Comment: This is not likely to work on many systems, particularly where plain `char` is signed (`x[0]` and `x[1]` will be sign-extended, so if the least significant one is negative, the upper byte will be set to all 1s by the bitwise OR).

Answer (score 1):

The portable solution:

```
unsigned char c[2];
long tmp;
int result;

tmp = (long)c[0] << 8 | c[1];
if (tmp < 32768)
    result = tmp;
else
    result = tmp - 65536;
```

This assumes that the bytes in the array represent a 16 bit, two's complement, big endian signed integer.  If they are a little endian integer, just swap `c[1]` and `c[0]`.

(In the highly unlikely case that it is ones' complement, use `65535` instead of `65536` as the value to subtract.  Sign-magnitude is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: I'd rather mask the result with 0x0000FFFF. This ensures that, even if sign bit expanded, you will grant the valute to be within 0x0000FFFF and 0.

Comment: @Mr.Gate: There is no need for any masking.  Since `c[0]` and `c[1]` are positive numbers between 0 and 255, `tmp` is a positive number in range 0 to 65535.  The only negative number is produced in the final subtraction - there is no chance of unwanted sign extension.