# Convert std::string buffer to integers

Tags: c++

I have a `std::string` containing four bytes received from a serial port. These bytes represent two `int16_t` in little endian. Since the software is going to run on x86 only, there is no need to change the endianness.

My first approach to get the individual integer values was this:

```
std::string inData = ...; // inData.length() = 4
int16_t measurement[2];
measurement[0] = ( (int16_t)inData[0] << 8 ) | (int16_t)inData[1];
measurement[1] = ( (int16_t)inData[2] << 8 ) | (int16_t)inData[3];
```

Well, the result looked like undefined behaviour. I expected casting from `inData[x]` to `int16_t` would yield having the four MSB set to zero, but that seems not to be true. So I tried this:

```
const uint8_t *castedData = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&inData[0]);
measurement[0] = ( (int16_t)castedData[0] << 8 ) | (int16_t)castedData[1];
measurement[1] = ( (int16_t)castedData[2] << 8 ) | (int16_t)castedData[3];
```

and it works as intended. However, is this the "correct" way? Or is there a way to achieve this without using `reinterpret_cast`?

I had a look at [Converting unsigned chars to signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782361/converting-unsigned-chars-to-signed-integer), but the accepted answer and the comments about aliasing confused me.

Comment: Both methods produces identical results for me. See http://ideone.com/bBKj6F

Comment: Use `std::basic_string<unsigned char>`.

Comment: `(inData[0] << 8) | (inData[1] & 0x00FF)`... no casts needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, the latter would be better with calling `c_str()` and casting the resulting pointer. The issue with former is that the std::string is most probably based on `signed char`. Therefore conversion to bigger `int` type will extend the sign bit and for example `0x80` will become `0xff80`.

If you fix the original with:

```
( (uint8_t)inData[0] << 8 ) | (uint8_t)inData[1];
```

it will work too...